# Using Shared Object Files

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I installed opencv 2.4.3 on ubuntu 12.04 using cmake. At the time of installation, .so files were put in /usr/local/lib directory. When I compile my code using the following line in terminal using the default location of .so files (i.e. /usr/local/lib) then it works fine

```
g++ fileName.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
```

I am trying to experiment with the shared object files. I copied the required shared object files from /usr/local/bin and put them in a new folder location /home/nishant/Desktop/lib. I copied the following files and their respective .so.2.4 and .so.2.4.3 files:
1) libopencv_core.so
2) libopencv_highgui.so
3) libopencv_imgproc.so

Then I changed there names to libcore.so , libhighgui.so and libimgproc.so respectively. I changed their name so that the old .so files should not be used from /usr/local/lib. Now when I try compiling my code using the shared object files in the new folder location then I get the following error:
Terminal Command:

```
g++ filename.cpp -L/home/nishant/Desktop/lib -lcore -lhighgui -limgproc
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhighgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -limgproc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is interesting to note that the following works:

```
g++ filename.cpp -L/home/nishant/Desktop/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
```

Reason: The .so files from /usr/local/lib are being used.
My Question : How can I use the .so files from the new folder location to make my code work.

Comment: are you sure /home/nishant/Desktop/lib/libcore.so is the actual library file, or if not, that the symbolic link points to the correct path? if you simply renamed the symlinks, you will not have changed their target and you will have to recreate the links to the renamed target. use `ls -l` to list the symlink target.

Answer (score 1):

I see three ways:

1.
Please update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - add path to your libraries before running `g++`.

2.
Please add the directory where your libraries are located to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then run `g++`.

3.
Please create a new file: `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` and add path do the directories with your libs to it and run:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Then run g++.